# Getting a typeError error in django project

Tags: python, django, error-handling, typeerror

I created a virtual environment for my new project, installed django and started the new project. However, whenever i run a line of code with manage.py i get this long error.

```
PS D:\My stuff\Website development\Isow website\isow> python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Database Entry:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your database related settings look like?

Comment: @deceze Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: Your `settings.py`; what does the `DATABASES` entry look like?

Comment: @deceze I edited my post and added the Database entry in my settings.py

Comment: could you try with string cast NAME path
str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"))

Comment: @iklinac Thank you. That seemed to work. But just for learning purposes, what was the problem?

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64047226/9225671) with a possible explanation of the issue. The issue seems to be fixed in newer Django versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [return database\_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database\_name TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046773/return-database-name-memory-or-mode-memory-in-database-name-typeerror)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem NAME is being converted to pathlib.Path ([WindowsPath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.WindowsPath)) object instead of string which then cannot be used in Django in same way as [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) expects strings (Not 100% sure as did not investigate in depth)

So casting in string would be appropriate

```
'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"))
```

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64047226/9225671) with a possible explanation of the issue. The issue seems to be fixed in newer Django versions.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you really execute your command in the venv (you should see `(venv)`)

If you are then as @iklinac said, this should fixe your issue:

```
'NAME': str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for Django>=3.1, the path module is included in place of the os module. Therefore, use:

```
'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')
```

So, DB sqlite3 settings will look like this in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}
```