# return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

Tags: python, django, mongodb, migrate, makemigrations

I am practicing Django but when I command `python manage.py makemigration` and `python manage.py migrate` then I got an error as show in the title. the full error is mentioned below:

```
C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\new_Socrai>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in
 execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in
 execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run
_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 261, in
 close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 380, in
 is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\Manan\python projects\djangoandmongo\dandm_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12,
 in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py file please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a typeError error in django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447011/getting-a-typeerror-error-in-django-project)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems like the setting [DATABASES - NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#name) expects a string, not a `Path` object.

In your settings try changing this line

```
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
```

to

```
'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),
```

so that `NAME` is a string instead of a `Path`.

---

The error comes from this line of code [`django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py#L13`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py#L13) and it seems that [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/77aa74cb70dd85497dbade6bc0f394aa41e88c94) solves the issue, so in `Django v3.1.1` there is no need to use `'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),` anymore, just using `'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',` should sufice.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by changing the line for database name in file `settings.py` to:

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

Comment: the `os.path.join(...)` operator does fix the issue.  An alternative with nice syntax is to keep using `pathlib.Path` and wrap it `str( ... )` whenever a string is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by changing the owner of the files to the current owner and starting the server using the following command `sudo -u <user_name> python3 manage.py runserver`. It seems it's a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by creating a virtual environment for the project. Run the following command to install the environment: python -m venv  learn more from https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.htmlnv.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).